# ruby regex to ensure email entering format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

Are we suppose to use regex with for loop?
For example If I want to ensure the user entering bunch of email in a text-box in the format like below, What is the best way to do it ?

```
Zoo bbb <zoo@email.com>, Alan T <at@gmail.xxx>, ........
```

How do we extract the information and put in names[], emails[].?

Comment: Regex could be used to solve it, as well as splitting the string by , and using string manipulation to extrapolate the dat. I would prefer to use regex as it is neater

Comment: You have to be very careful if you want this to work on every email address. The standard allow VERY weird addresses, like `"This is, an evil, address"@uk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to use regex the following pattern would match:

```
<([\w+\.\@]+)>+


Match 1
1.  zoo@email.com
Match 2
1.  at@gmail.xxx
```

You can test it out on: http://rubular.com

What you would do is count the matches found by using `scan`

here is the example code i put together

```
s = "Zoo bbb <zoo@email.com>, Alan T <at@gmail.xxx>"

names = []
emails = []

s.scan(/[\s]?([\w\s]+)<([\w+\.\@]+)>+/).each do | m |
  names << m[0]
  emails << m[1]
end

puts "names = #{names}"
puts "emails = #{emails}"
```

output:

```
names = ["Zoo bbb ", "Alan T "]
emails = ["zoo@email.com", "at@gmail.xxx"]
```

Comment: Thanks! But what is the \. in the middle do ??? The pattern seems not very straight forward to me. How about <([\w+\@\.+]+)> , it works on rubular, is this one correct?

Comment: the \. is for the full stop in the domain

the [ ] means that they are grouped togeather so effectively what I am saying is anything in this group

\w+ = a letter
\. = a full stop
\@ = an @ symbol

has to occur one or more times inside the < >

as a valid email has to contain all of those! the order of the elements doesnt actually matter inside the group and the plus symbol goes on the outside to signify that there will be one or more occurrences of these inside. does that clear it up?

Comment: Though not in the question, this regexp fails to completely match names with initials (J. Edgar Hoover, John F. Kennedy) or hyphens (Stephen Hartle–Hawking).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```ruby
test_string = "Zoo bbb <zoo@email.com>, Alan T <at@gmail.xxx>, James B <james.bond@m5.gov.co.uk>"

# Create regexp to match emails given this format "Alan T <at@gmail.xxx>, ..."
regexp = /\s*,?\s*(.*?)<(.*?)>/

# Scan string for regexp matches
matches = test_string.scan(regexp)

# Let's see what the matches are...
p matches # [["Zoo bbb ", "zoo@email.com"], ["Alan T ", "at@gmail.xxx"], ["James B ", "james.bond@m5.gov.co.uk"]] 

# Iterating over matches is easy
matches.each do |match_array|
    puts "Name:\t #{match_array[0]}"
    puts "Email:\t #{match_array[1]}"
end

# To extract all names and emails into individual arrays:
names = []
emails = []
matches.each do |match_array|
    names << match_array[0]
    emails << match_array[1]
end

p names # ["Zoo bbb ", "Alan T ", "James B "] 
p emails # ["zoo@email.com", "at@gmail.xxx", "james.bond@m5.gov.co.uk"]
```